# string was not recognized as a valid DateTime on datagridview

Tags: c#, mysql, database, datagridview

i'm trying to copy time from datagridview to the datetimepicker box.

```
private void datagridview1_CellContentClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{  
  if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
  {
     DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
     dateTimePicker1.text = row.cells["up_hours"].Value.ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `row.cells["up_hours"].Value.ToString()` ?

Comment: the up_hours is a dateTimepicker. that i saved on mysql showing HH:mm

Comment: can you try with  dateTimePicker1.Value instead of .text and try parsing to Date?

Answer (score 0):

```
        private void datagridview1_CellContentClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                if (row.Cells["up_hours"].Value == null)
                {
                    dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " ";
                    dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                }
                else
                {
                    dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Long;
                    dateTimePicker1.Text = row.Cells["up_hours"].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

We just need to update DateTimePicket Format as per our requirement while setting values, this will work for you please try this.

Comment: what was the error can you please post your exception here